# Reduce the polynomial terms in logistic regression (glm)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, polynomial

I've three categorical variables A, B and C with 5 levels each. The model I'm trying to fit is

`glm(Y~A+B+C, family=binomial())`

How can I remove the higher order polynomial contrasts terms from the model after making sure that the AIC and null deviance is improved?

Comment: Can you clarify the polynomial terms you are referring to? I don't see any. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your ultimate goal here? There may be a better way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: @gung The polynomial terms I was referring to are the contrasts: A.L, A.Q, A.C, B.L, B.Q, B.C, C.L, C.Q, and C.C. Though, the quadratic and cubic terms of Factor C are insignificant and I want to reduce the model.

Answer (score 3):

That would bias the model and invalidate statistical inference.  And I didn't see any polynomial terms in your model.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the polynomial contrasts.

Comment: You can't have polynomial contrasts for variables not in the model.

Comment: I figured it out. The default setting of contrasts in R for ordered data was contr.poly. I changed it.

Comment: Please correct your model formula.